# Loopback: Event resetPasswordRequest not called after reset

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to tap into the password reset process on Loopback, so I can send an e-mail with the instructions to the user. I created a custom model called 'user' that extends 'User'. Then I added "User.on('resetPasswordRequest'...", but it never gets executed. Please check the console.log on the user.js

### model-config.json

```
{
...

  "user": {
    "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "emailVerificationRequired": false
    }
  },
...
}
```

---

### user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "accessType": "READ",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

---

### user.js

```
module.exports = function(User) {

  console.log('It prints this log here.');

  User.on('resetPasswordRequest', function(info) {

    console.log('But it does not print this log here ever.');

    var url = 'http://www.example.com/reset-password';
    var html = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?access_token=' + info.accessToken.id + '">here</a>';
    loopback.Email.send({
      to: info.email,
      from: 'mail@example.com',
      subject: 'My Subject',
      html: html
    }, function() {
      console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
      if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
    });
  });

};
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. How do you trigger the event? Did you check LoopBack [user management example project](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management)? Reset password flow is a part of it.

Comment: Hi @IvanSchwarz, thank you for your help. That is exactly the demo that I used in the first place. I am triggering the event on the API Panel that Loopback creates. The user.js file is executed by Loopback, as I can see that first console.log printing on terminal. But the console.log inside the User.on is never printed.

Comment: I've just cloned [loopback-getting-started](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started) repo, pasted in your `user` files, adjusted `model-config.json` and both `console.log()` got printed. I'm wondering...didn't you forget to hide the built-in `User` model in `model-config.json`? You might be triggering the password reset event for a built-in model rather than your extended one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so @IvanSschwarz was right. Thank you so much! My initial code was correct, but it was missing a small change on the model-config.json: I needed to hide the User model for some reason. So I also took the opportunity and changed my model name from "user" to "member", to follow the loopback good practices guide lines.

```
   ...
   "User": {
     "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
     "public": false
   },
   "member": {
     "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
     "public": true,
     "options": {
       "emailVerificationRequired": true
     }
   },
   ....
```

I believe that the other suggestions could potentially work as well, but I wanted to extend the User model through JSON and also leverage the built-in remote method Reset Password from the Users model. So thank you guys!

Comment: If anyone wants to see the final code to take it as a reference, here it goes:
https://github.com/fabionolasco/falsecognates

Answer (score 0):

The solution is explained here:
http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html#setting-up-a-custom-model

So you will need:

```
User.setup = function() {
  var User = this;
  // since setup is called for every extended model
  // the extended model will also have the event listener
  User.on('resetPasswordRequest', function() {
    ///Do your stuff here
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks like the ideal solution. However that code never gets executed. When I put a console.log before User.setup, it prints the content. The console.log inside the User.setup is never printed. Just out of curiosity, how would the full user.js file look like on your suggestion?

Comment: Hi @GeoffreyMureithi, do I need to setup something like: var User = Model.extends('User'); ? If so, what would be Model?

Comment: hmm something like `var user = Model.extends('User');` is needed

Comment: Model should be from the loopback object `loopback.Model`, and (i think) it should be accessible at `User.app.Model`

Answer (score -1):

Don't you simply miss to define a remote method in order to call your code?
This is what I would do:

**user.js**

```
    module.exports = function(User) {

      console.log('It prints this log here.');

      User.resetPasswordRequest = function (info, cb) {

        console.log('But it does not print this log here ever.');

        var url = 'http://www.example.com/reset-password';
        var html = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?access_token=' + info.accessToken + '">here</a>';
        loopback.Email.send({
          to: info.email,
          from: 'mail@example.com',
          subject: 'My Subject',
          html: html
        }, function() {
          console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
          if (err) {
             cb(err, false);
             return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
          }
          cb(err, true):
        });
      });

    User.remoteMethod('resetPasswordRequest', {
            description: 'Send a mail to an User to permit him to reset his password',
            accepts: {arg: 'info', type: 'object', required: true},
            returns: {arg: 'mailSend', type: 'boolean'},
            http: {verb: 'post'}
        });

};
```

Then, using the Explorer or calling the API via REST while posting a your *info* json like:

```
{
 accessToken: xxx,
 email: xxx
}
```

And don't forget to update your ACLs in **user.json** so you can call the method from remote:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "resetPasswordRequest"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: There is already a [built-in remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/User-REST-API.html#reset-password) on a `User` base model to request a password reset. It should be enough to use `POST /users/reset` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you F3L1X79 , but I agree with @IvanSchwarz. Plus, I believe that in your suggestion you are not sending the correct password-reset token. But anyways, I tried to implement it and I got: Unhandled error for request POST /api/users/resetPasswordRequest: Error: Shared class  "User" has no method handling POST /resetPasswordRequest

Comment: Maybe it's beacause the name "resetPasswordRequest" is protected. I wasn't aware this was a built-in method. You might want to change the name to another.